# How to add custom attributes to function callback Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, bind

I have this code

```
doPurchase = function(amount) {
  transactionCompleteCallbackImpl.bind(this, amount);
  iclient.initiatePurchase({
    amount: amount,
    cashout: '0',
    integratedReceipt: true
  }, {
    statusMessageCallback: statusMessageCallbackImpl,
    questionCallback: questionCallbackImpl,
    receiptCallback: receiptCallbackImpl,
    transactionCompleteCallback: transactionCompleteCallbackImpl
  });
};
```

I do not control the iclient code as it is loaded from an external source, however I wish to add the amount for the purchase which (inexplicably) isn't included in the data returned by the transactionCompleteCallback:

```
transactionCompleteCallbackImpl = function(response, transactionAmount) {
  console.log(transactionAmount);
  return console.log(response);
};
```

this logs undefined first for transactionAmount and the original Response data seccondly

As you can see I have tried bind which I have read can be used in this way but I think something is wrong as I still can't access the data in my callback function.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you forget to include some code in your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind() will create a new method but not modify the method, so your first line should be

```js
transactionCompleteCallbackImpl = transactionCompleteCallbackImpl.bind(this, amount);
```

Try it!

Comment: disregard last, seems to be working now !! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

[`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) returns a *new* function with the correct context (`this` value) and supplied arguments prepended.

So you could probably just change the `.bind()` line to be:

```
transactionCompleteCallback = transactionCompleteCallback.bind(this, amount);
```

so that you replace the `transactionCompleteCallback` function with one that is bound to the correct value for `this` and will have the `amount` value as it's first argument.

Comment: Thanks GregL!! Sorry I marked huaogo as the answer as he got in first with a more succinct answer, however yours is also excellent with lots of information (if with a small typo on the function names) thanks for your help :D